# c# , Timer disactivate prevent sleep function

Tags: c#, timer

I use as following c# code to prevent sleep and monitor off:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    // Import SetThreadExecutionState Win32 API and necessary flags
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);
    public const uint ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000;
    public const uint ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001;
    public const uint ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002;
}
```

and Calling this function on Formload:

```
private void PreventSleep()
{
    NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(NativeMethods.ES_CONTINUOUS |  NativeMethods.ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
}

private void PreventMonitorOff()
{
    NativeMethods.SetThreadExecutionState(NativeMethods.ES_CONTINUOUS | NativeMethods.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED);
}
```

This way of code gives me timeless preventing. What I want is a limit of time.

Let say sleep after 40 minutes if there is no user who working with the computer. I want to deactivate those functions after 40 minutes. And then when the user finish using the computer I want to activate and prevent in 40 minutes. It will be like a loop. Like
I want to prevent windows from going to sleep only in 40 minutes , then sleeping as usual if there is no user who using the computer. Then when the computer is free from user, I want to wait in 40 minutes Before it's going to sleep again.

I tried using Timer with interval 2400000 (40 minutes):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PreventSleep();
    PreventMonitorOff();
}
```

and Calling those functions:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
```

How to do a loop with those functions, and will this code know that "Now there is movement of mouse or keybord and activate sleeping after 40 minutes"? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no reasonable non-hack way, because you are going against user settings. You either define that your thread is "so important" that it keeps the system alive or you respect the user settings. What you are trying to do is override the user settings in the system configuration. Therefore the correct answer to your question is: Instruct the user to set the sleep time to your desired value (40 minutes), if they don't want to, respect that.

Comment: Good question, but please be careful using your terminology. The "functions" you refer to are actually "sub-routines".

Answer (score 0):

With `ES_CONTINUOUS` you don't need to call it periodically.

So set a timer for 40 minutes, then remove the `ES_CONTINOUS` flag (see MSDN). The difficulty will be to detect whether the user is actually idle. If you don't have a specific action to determine this, it would be better to let the OS decide. You may use powercfg API to force the timeouts.